# flipclock.js Background color

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the background colour of flipclock.js

I managed to change the background but the whole counter was changed I want the hour section to be in red colour, minutes in black colour and seconds in green colour.

Comment: Can you post any code?

Comment: http://flipclockjs.com I'm using this. Thank you

Comment: No, you need to post YOUR current code and you need to post it here, within your question. Use the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* button for that when you [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/1FB31388ye580NovuY9Y?p=preview

```
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(2) li a div div.inn,
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(3) li a div div.inn
{
    background : red;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(5) li a div div.inn,
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(6) li a div div.inn
{
    background : black;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(8) li a div div.inn,
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(9) li a div div.inn
{
    background : green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the example in the site. It seems each section is just a `<ul>`, with no class name or id for delineation (bad practice). So its perhaps hard to change one without affecting the rest.

If that's the issue, it should be possible to just differentiate between the hours, minutes and seconds divs based on order.

```
.flip-counter ul.flip:nth-child(2) .inn {
    background : red;
}
.flip-counter ul.flip:nth-child(3) .inn {
    background : red;
}

.flip-counter ul.flip:nth-child(5) .inn {
    background : black;
}
.flip-counter ul.flip:nth-child(6) .inn {
    background : black;
}

.flip-counter ul.flip:nth-child(8) .inn {
    background : green;
}
.flip-counter ul.flip:nth-child(9) .inn {
    background : green;
}
```